# Server Error in '/' Application CRUD Views

Tags: c#

Im very new to MVC 4 and Im getting this error when try to use the CRUD views in my controller.

**Error**

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /appointment/Details/A00001

**Controller Method**

//
        // GET: /Appointment/Details/5

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
    {
        Appointment appointment = db.Appointment.Find(id);
        if (appointment == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(appointment);
```

**Connection String**

Comment: <add name="GHZDbContext"
            connectionString="Data Source=54.213.93.39,1433;Initial Catalog=IS3G8_DB1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=******* "
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Look at what you're doing - it's very likely that the MVC stuff is just fine, and your appointment is null, which returns the 404 in your code. Just debug your regular code.